# Replace CRLF with LF in textarea before form submit (client-side)

Tags: javascript, html, line-endings

Certain server scripts breaks if it recieve \r\n instead of \n.

I cannot edit the server, only client side web page.

If I submit HTML form with textarea with lineendings, it sends \r\n.

I tried to replace using javascript before submit, but browser still send \r\n (maybe the textarea automaticaly normalizes lineending back?)

```
data = document.getElementById("data").value;
data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
document.getElementById("data").value = data;
document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
```

Comment: did you try to escape CR by `\\r` ?

Comment: This is complex, since when you're reading the value in JS, you get only LFs, but CRLFs are sent to the server. Unfortunately this is [expected behavior](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmltextareaelement). You've to go with AJAX to submit the wanted value.